# WebStorm Code Completion dones't work without semicolon

Tags: webstorm, code-completion

I don't use semicolon at end of line in JavaScript.

And I find WebStorm doesn't have `Code Completion` without semicolon.

I'm not good at English, see the screenshots.

Without semicolon, don't have `const` suggested:

[image: Screenshot 1: without semicolon, don't have <code>const</code> suggest]

First line without semicolon, second line only have 3 suggest, and don't have `const`.

With semicolon, have `const` suggested:

[image: Screenshot 2: with semicolon, have <code>const</code> suggest]

First line have semicolon and have `const` suggest.

I tired clean `.WebStorm2019.3` and use default config, but `Code Completion` still don't work.

All the keywords don't suggest, like `const`, `if`, `while`, `let`, `function` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WEB-43146](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43146) is fixed in 2019.3.3 that is coming soon